# Closing colorbox after submit

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm using colorbox module to load the login form, but after submit the form the page reloaded inside the "iframe" .

what i want to close the color box "iframe" and reloading the main page.

i searched for a long time but i can't find any solution.

Comment: If you display a form within an "iframe" then it makes sense that the form submits the posted data to a page within the iframe. I think what you need is showing the login form as "inline" content within colorbox.

Comment: I will try it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 
parent.jQuery.fn.colorbox.close();

for closing colorbox, when submitting form.

like,  add the onClick event inside the submit button code:

```
<input type='submit' value="Submit' onClick='parent.jQuery.fn.colorbox.close();'>
```

Comment: What if the username or password incorrect? should it the iframe still appear and display error message?

Comment: I tried it and the iframe close before the user been loged in

Comment: the question is asking to close the iframe/colorbox "after" submit, not after a click.